# Differences in subsetting data frame methods

Tags: r, dataframe

```
tmp1 <- data.frame(x = 10, y = NA, z = NA)
```

Actual:

```
> tmp1[ ,!is.na(tmp1)]
[1] 10
```

Desired:

```
> tmp1[ ,!is.na(tmp1)]
   x
1 10
```

Pfft, why ?

```
> tmp1[-c(2:3)]
   x
1 10
```

*grumblegrumblegrumble*

```
> tmp1[ ,-c(2:3)]
[1] 10
```

I'm sure R is doing exactly what I ask, but it's not doing exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask for only one column of a data.frame, `R` gives you an atomic vector, UNLESS you specify that you want to keep the result as a data.frame:

```
tmp1[,-(2:3),drop=F]
```

Also noteworthy:

- `2:3` is already a vector, so you don't need `c(2:3)`, but you do need `-(2:3)` to distribute the negative sign.
- `tmp1[-c(2:3)]` is a bit confusing because data.frames are also lists. It means remove the second and third item of the list `tmp1`, which are columns. I'd avoid that kind of notation but it's up to you.

Comment: I should have looked in `?'['` not `?data.frame`... my mistake